# 70-432 : SQL Server 2008 Implementation and Maintenance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Has anybody taken this certification exam?  If so, how many years of experience do you have as a SQL Server DBA and how hard did you find the exam?

Comment: Just curious, why 70-432 but not 70-462 - Administering Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Databases (the most recent one)?

Comment: @gmsantos What is the difference between 70-432 and 70-462?

Comment: @TamWol 462 is SQL 2012 Administering and 432 is SQL 2008 Implementation and Maintenance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn more reading [Guide To MCITP: SQL Server 2008 Administration](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MCTS/75078/), but the impression I got was that the 70-432 is an exam to test your basic skills and can be handled by even an "accidental DBA" with the right amount of studying and exploration in SQL Server 2008 Developer's Edition

> 70-432 is the basic exam and covers a range of general SQL Server
>   administration areas. 70-450 is more advanced and covers all the areas
>   of 70-432, plus higher-level DBA tasks such as high availability and
>   infrastructure design. Be aware that all questions are multiple-choice
>   (more on this later).

Answer (score 0):

I'm preparing for this exam at the moment. I have quite a lot of experience as a database developer, but limited experience as a DBA. I'm finding preparing for the exam quite tricky. Typically for me when I want to do something, I would consult books online, and then complete the task. However with the exam, a lot of stuff is expected to be committed to memory.

I've found the official exam guide 'MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-432) by Mike Hotek' to be reasonable, but not nearly comprehensive enough. I recommend using the guide as an outline and then looking at books online for additional detail. I think the reviews on Amazon are quite negative mainly because the guide won't give you all the information you need to pass the exam.

If you want a decent overview of DBA work with SQL Server try this book 'SQL Server 2008 Administration in Action by Rod Colledge'. While it is NOT an exam preparation guide it is reasonable if you want a second perspective. This book also doesn't cover some 'advanced' topics which I understand appear in the exam such as replication and some partition related topics.

Can anyone confirm that all the questions in the actual exam are multi-choice or are there simulation type questions as well? Also approximately how many questions are there likely to be?

While full-time professional DBAs with a number of years experience may be able to pass this test without significant preparation. Part-time and accidental DBAs will need to do quite a bit of work.